# What happens to my Doppelganger if it becomes a Vampire?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-templates

I am playing a Doppelganger, and I would like to become a vampire. First, is it possible for a doppelganger to become one? Second, what exactly changes? I read that one loses all racial abilities. Does that mean i can no longer change shape and detect thoughts?

Comment: A Vampilganger (Doppelpire?) would be a pretty scary villain, now that I think about it.

Answer (score 8):

> “Vampire” is an acquired template that can be added to any humanoid or monstrous humanoid creature (referred to hereafter as the base creature).

Doppelgangers are monstrous humanoids, so they are eligible to become vampires, yes.

> A vampire uses all the base creature’s statistics and special abilities except as noted here.

So no, a doppelganger does not lose any statistics or special abilities *except* as noted in the [vampire entry](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/vampire.htm).

For example,

> Increase from the base creature as follows: Str +6, Dex +4, Int +2, Wis +2, Cha +4. As an undead creature, a vampire has no Constitution score.

Your doppelganger would lose his Constitution score, going to Con — and thus using a +0 bonus on anything he adds his Constitution modifier to. This may result in less HP, almost-certainly results in lower Fortitude saves and Concentration checks, and so on.

For the rest of the changes, please see the vampire entry. The changes are just applied on top of your doppelganger.

Comment: You beat me to answering this. I was writing almost the same answer when yours popped up!

Comment: Regarding the saves - a Vampire also becomes an Undead, which gives them a few different interactions regarding fortitude saves in some cases. As far as I remember, I think they had some sort of "can't fail" clause to them.

Comment: Yep, just checked - "Immunity to any effect that requires a Fortitude save (unless the effect also works on objects or is harmless)". So, despite being _true_ that the OP will end up with lower Fortitude saves, it will also come with several immunities!

Comment: @TSar Yes, that is true, but things that do force an undead creature to make a Fortitude save are definitely a weakness for one.

Comment: That's perfectly accurate. Undead is a pretty interesting type with a wide range of built-in traits. Anyways, your answer is on point and I gave it my +1!

Comment: @KRyan I don't really understand the concept of vampires being unable to cross running water. "Vampires are also unable to cross running water, although they can be carried over it while resting in their coffins or aboard a ship."

Comment: @Skyrimpro12 That is a different and unrelated question.

Comment: @Skyrimpro12: It hearkens back to legends that were used as source material. I'd suggest a new question about it!