# Can a Lycanthrope become a Vampire?

Tags: dnd-5e, undead, curses, lycanthropy

As a DM, I'm wondering whether a Lycanthrope curse is canceled when such a monster is killed by a Vampire bite and becomes a Vampire Spawn. There doesn't seem to be indications against it in the Monster Manual. If anything, the MM says that the humanoid being transformed in a Vampire keeps most of its existing features (a few stats are eventually increased).

As far as D&D as a whole is concerned, it looks like it was a possibility in various versions such as [in 3.5](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/96965).

Is there something in 5e that would tell something different?

Especially, the 5e rules are pretty strongly suggesting that most features are not cumulative. However, Lycanthropy and Undead are not the same, so it would seem that they can be cumulative. At the same time, if the Lycanthropy is viewed as a disease, once Undead that disease would *disappear*. But the MM clearly says it's a curse and a curse doesn't just disappear when you transform to an undead?

Comment: Only Michael Corvin

Comment: I beleive there is something that states a Curse only lasts as long as the creature is "alive" - I.e. their HP is above 0, or they are not "undead". I am yet to find this evidence though

Comment: @Ben Actually, Raise Dead and Resurrection say _"[...] This spell doesn’t, however, remove magical diseases, curses, or similar effects; [...]"_. So it says the opposite of what you were saying (i.e. even in death, you bring your curses along). On the other hand True Resurrection does fix everything.

Comment: if this was World of Darkness: Samual Haight started Human, became Werewolf, became a free ghoul, became a sorta-mage, and finally blew up when he tried to *be embraced by an antediluvian and then promptly diablerie that one*.

Answer (score 4):

### Nothing directly prevents it.

The key question here is about who can be affected by different curses.

The Monster Manual (p.206) says:

> ***Curse of Lycanthropy.*** A **humanoid** creature can be afflicted with the curse of lycanthropy after being wounded by a lycanthrope...

For an NPC, it's inarguable: A lycanthrope (afflicted or not) is a *humanoid (shapechanger)*. The "Player Characters as Lycanthropes" sidebar states that you get the nonhumanoid form's speeds, immunities, traits, and actions that don't involve equipment, but it doesn't mention gaining the shapechanger tag, though I assume the intent is that you do become a shapechanger. That doesn't actually do much, though; you're still a humanoid.

The Vampire stat block (p.297) says:

> ***Bite.*** [...] A **humanoid** slain in this way and then buried in the ground rises the following night as a vampire spawn under the vampire's control.

So a vampire spawn is an undead, which is not a valid target for the curse of lycanthropy.  But does that matter?

The curse of lycanthropy can only be *passed* to a humanoid, but it doesn't seem to go away or break if the creature type changes to undead later, and nothing says the curse is removed when its target dies, so there seems no rules-as-written reason to say that dying and rising as a vampire would break the curse. It might be mechanically unwieldy to have so many extra traits and actions on a creature, but it doesn't seem technically problematic.

That said, as DM you could certainly decide that there's a reason the two states can't coexist, or that the vampire's Shapechange ability replaces the Lycanthrope's Shapechange, making the hybrid and animal forms inaccessible even if they're still technically a lycanthrope. I don't see anything off-hand that would be totally broken about a vampiric lycanthrope, you just need some fairly specific weaponry to fight them.

So far as I can see, there's nothing that stops you from having a ghost werewolf, vampire werewolf, or zombie werewolf in your game.  Whether the ability to spread the lycanthropic curse remains in their undead form, I can't say. In theory it does, but feel free to do what you want to do.

Comment: As a side note, I'm a DM and that would be the villain. I think it would be very difficult for a PC to be playing an evil character that likes to kill other people indiscreetly. Along those lines, would the change of alignment be a concern for the Lycanthrope?

Comment: @AlexisWilke That you're the DM and looking for it villainous purposes would be a good addition to the question. We like that kind of context, because it helps us help you with the specific problem you're facing.

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing in the rules stopping a lycanthropy from becoming a vampire.

You can find the rules for lycanthropes and vampires in the Monster Manual under the sections with their respective names.

Comment: Yeah, which means now the bite is a double curse...

Comment: You should cite your source, not only quote it.

Comment: Which rulebook (and best: page) is this from?

Comment: I am also very curious where this comes from

Comment: 5e has several sourcebooks, the one that covers monsters is the Monster Manual

Comment: @AlexisWilke it may be helpful if you explain your assumption. There's nothing in the rules saying that vampirism is a curse, nor that curses end on death. It's hard to prove a negative especially when the negative is not spelled out. As you note, and I confirm, nothing in the rules says it can't be done. Isn't that enough for you?

Comment: A vampire lycanthrope would be scary to face with it's damage resistances and vampire spawn...